# Error:(22, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

here's my gradle file

I am getting this error

> Error:(22, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 26
}
productFlavors {
}
}
dependencies {
}
```

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? It builds the gradle files for you, and they do not look this minimal

Comment: yes latest version of android studio @cricket_007

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Then how did you get such a small gradle file without a plugin applied?

Comment: i accidentally deleted my API's and when i updated my android studio, this was my gradle file @cricket_007

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply a plugin to your `build.gradle` file. Only then you will be able to use the `android` block. Add any of these two lines at the top of your `build.gradle` file:

- Application : `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`
- Library : `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

Answer (score 1):

Your App Gradle should look like something like this

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.armenhovhannisyan.backpaper.backpaper"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

}
```

Comment: Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\NEERAJ\AndroidStudioProjects\Loginsignup\build.gradle">Open File</a>................................. i replaced my build.gradle with the above and now it shows error(1.0)

Comment: how you have created your project ? the gradle shouldn't look like that . the gradle which i send here is made for my package you have to change to yours

Comment: Error:(40, 0) Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
i made some changes in your build.gradle and now i am getting this

Comment: how have you  created the project ? can you send me few more pics the gradle is automatically build when you create new project